# Send Notification Email with Follow Button Community Napili

Tags: community, knowledge, napili, community-builder, articles

Somebody can help me to understand the Follow Button on Napili Template

(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_user_profile_follow_button_napili.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

Because I'm trying to follow a topic and when I enable the option to send me an email notification, this functionality doesn't work, every time what I publish a new article.

[image]

Maybe needs some extra configurations?
Thank you.

Comment: This functionality is only for follow topics in Feeds.

Comment: After adding this configuration, you must need turn on Feed Tracking for each article type you want members to follow.